# What qualification you are looking for?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, word-order, questions, subject-verb-inversion

Well this may be a very silly and obvious question but it's bothering me so I am asking it here. I am writing a letter and I asked the question

> What qualification **are you** looking for?

However my colleague says it should be

> What qualification **you are** looking for?

Well, some how I think my version is correct but I cannot justify it grammatically, can someone tell me which of the interrogation is correct? and why?

Comment: if this is a letter about employment prospects, you'd probably ask about "competencies" instead of "qualifications". Few jobs require qualifications per-se. Competencies covers both qualifications and all important key desirable attributes desired. Obviously none of this matters if the letter is about qualifying something instead.

Comment: @Chris the comment is off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When asking a question that begins with a "questioning word" like *what*, *who*, *which*, *when* or *how*, the verb will usually be placed before the subject.  This is called "inversion", because it's the opposite order from an ordinary non-question sentence.  You can read about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_%28linguistics%29).

In the case that you've cited, the first version is correct.  The second version is something that a native speaker would never say.

Comment: Also, unless you are specifically talking about a single qualification, the question typically uses the plural: "What qualifications are you looking for?"

Comment: Yes, very true.  Very good point.